# How can I access an std::map property inside an std::vector iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, stl

I have the following type:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, double> Tick;
```

and a vector:

```
std::vector<Tick> dataSegment;
```

I want to iterate through the vector and calculate the sum of a particular property of each map item:

```
double sum = 0.0;

for (std::vector<Tick>::iterator iterator = dataSegment.begin(); iterator != dataSegment.end(); ++iterator) {
    sum += iterator->find("close");
}
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'iterator' (aka
>         '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator, double>,
>         std::__1::__tree_node, double>, void *> *, long> >'))
>           sum += iterator->find("close");

I've also tried:

```
for (std::vector<Tick>::iterator iterator = dataSegment.begin(); iterator != dataSegment.end(); ++iterator) {
    sum += (*iterator).find("close");
}
```

but this produces a similar error:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'iterator' (aka
>         '__map_iterator<__tree_iterator, double>,
>         std::__1::__tree_node, double>, void *> *, long> >'))
>           sum += (*iterator).find("close");

Comment: `sf::map::find` returns an iterator, not a value.

Comment: Ah! That's true, looking at the documentation. How would I access a property?

Comment: Through deferencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns an iterator. If you want to use that, you'll have to check it first:

```
auto mit = iterator->find("close");
if (mit != iterator->end()) {
    sum += mit->second;
}
```

On the other hand, you could use [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) instead (which will insert defaults into the map if the key isn't found):

```
sum += (*iterator)["close"];
```

Comment: The method `at(const Key& key)` will not insert a new item if not found. It will throw  `std::out_of_range` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at (C++11 and above)

Comment: Good call on using `.at()`. I'll try using that.